# Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) - issues with yahoo's charting

Tags: google-chrome

This is what happens and how to reproduce it :

(1) Start Chrome

(2) Type "s&p 500" into the URL bar

(3) Browser stops just before it renders the chart. Processor usage goes to 100% and stays there, drive light flickers constantly. Everything slows to a crawl but I can still restart.

This only happens with the Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) that I have installed, and only after I did an apt-get update/upgrade cycle.

I am inclined to think that somehow,the something that renders the chart when you do that is blowing up the browser.

Would appreciate any help, updates or anything. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable graphics acceleration.

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click the menu button (It says Customize and
   control Google Chrome when you hover over it) at the top-right
   corner of the window.
3. Click Settings.
4. Scroll down and click the Show
   advanced settings link at the bottom of the window.
5. Scroll down to
   the System section and uncheck the box to the left of Use hardware
   acceleration when available.

Comment: Sorry no change detected. Still still seems to thrash. It's obviously something that happened either with Chrome or Ubuntu's latest update. The problem is I don't know what. 

one@One-PC:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

This is 16.04.2, just released a month ago.  Xorg coredumped, says report is mangled and unreadable. Is there a way to revert to 16.04.1 ?